# @font-face in my css file doesn't load font files in my Node.js and express framework

Tags: css, node.js, express, fonts, font-face

The below code doesn't make a call to download the file. I am using this within a Node.js and Express framework.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), 
       url('../../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), 
       url('../../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

The above code should be downloading glyphicon font in the browser, but it doesn't do so. In the developer toolbar of Chrome and Firefox I don't see any call being made to the specified URL.

Could someone please explain why

Comment: Not sure, what your question is...

Comment: The above code should be downloading glyphicon font in the browser, but it doesn't do so. In developer toolbar of chrome and Firefox I don't see any call being made to the specified URL.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! I've edited your question a little as it came through the review queue.  In particular, I've formatted the code block a little just to make it a bit more readable.  I also removed the `snippet` markup - this should be used only for a runnable piece of code e.g. javascript.  Finally - I added the extra info from your comment to the body of the question as it is crucial and added the css tag so more people might see your question and be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

font file doesn't get loaded until use them. 
I was trying to load glyphicon font but i was not using them in my html. Hence it wasn't loaded.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer after finding the solution through your own  research :)  Welcome to Stack Overflow!